# Plotting functions with gnuplot on a predifined x axis

Tags: plot, gnuplot

I am trying to plot some functions that I exported from octave.

The files are structured as follows:

Every line has a number that corresponds to `f(something)` and only that number.

For example the `y(x) = x` for x in `[0:10]` with step `.1` function would have a file like this:

```
0
0.1
0.2
0.3
```

and so on...

By default gnuplot plots everything like it is `f(line_number) = number_on_the_line`

This `something` changes for every file, some are between `(-100,100)` with step of `.1` and others are between `(0,2000)` with a step of `1`.

How can I force gnuplot to use my range to correspond the number on the line?

I tried `set xrange [-100:100]` but this doesn't plot anything for `[-100:0]` since there are no negative lines.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must transform the line number (zeroth column) so that it matches your expected x-value. For the xrange from -100 to 100 in steps of 0.1 use

```
x(n) = -100 + 0.1 * n
plot 'file' using (x($0)):1
```